# How to read a file from node_modules (custom module) like babel reading .babelrc files

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules

I have a custom package. I tried to use 'fs' as dependancy. but I am getting following error. (but I can see installed module in node_modules folder)

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'`

then I make changes to webpack config as

`node: {
    fs: empty
}`

then I could able to build. Later I have installed this package in other project and I could n't able to read file. 'error: fs is not installed.'

My goal:

I would like to read  a read a file which is under 'src/' folder (like babel reading .babelrc file) from my custom npm package which is under node_module.

Please advice! thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

[Just adding my work around. It could help someone.]

After spending enough time I find my mistake.
Built-in node module 'fs' will not available in frond-end when while compile and load in browser.

To get access for `fs` module, I have to execute script (like `node ../abc.js` this script will load config file from 'src/' folder) through pre-install/post-install in my custom package. This comes with a problem, any changes to config file need package installation.

I took another approach with webpack. Created a webpack-loader which will be called when my package code is getting parsed and then custom package will get access to 'fs' module to read a file in 'src/' folder. Changes to config will be re-compiled with webpack.